# How to let dnsmasq transfer a reverse zone?

Tags: domain-name-system, dnsmasq

Following the [documentation for auth-zone](http://www.thekelleys.org.uk/dnsmasq/docs/dnsmasq-man.html), I tried to declare my `dnsmasq` server as authoritative for the `10.0.0.0/8` zone (I serve several IP sub-ranges in 10.x).

Unfortunately, whatever I try I end up with

```
Sep 07 14:37:36 bind named[6812]: transfer of '10.in-addr.arpa/IN' from 10.100.10.254#53: connected using 10.200.0.158#57941
Sep 07 14:37:36 bind named[6812]: transfer of '10.in-addr.arpa/IN' from 10.100.10.254#53: failed while receiving responses: SERVFAIL
Sep 07 14:37:36 bind named[6812]: transfer of '10.in-addr.arpa/IN' from 10.100.10.254#53: Transfer status: SERVFAIL
Sep 07 14:37:36 bind named[6812]: transfer of '10.in-addr.arpa/IN' from 10.100.10.254#53: Transfer completed: 0 messages, 0 records, 0 bytes, 0.001 secs (0 bytes/sec)
```

on the secondary BIND server (the direct zones are transferred OK).

**How should I set this up?**

The whole current configuration file for `dnsmasq`:

```
no-resolv
no-poll
server=1.1.1.1
server=8.8.4.4
expand-hosts
domain=example.com
domain-needed

auth-server=example.com,lan0,br0
auth-zone=example.com,10.0.0.0/8,lan0,br0
auth-sec-servers=rpi1,bind

dhcp-range=10.100.10.1,10.100.10.230,240h
dhcp-range=10.100.20.1,10.100.20.230,240h
(... more DHCP ranges ...)
dhcp-option=option:ntp-server,129.104.30.42,195.220.194.193
dhcp-option=option:dns-server,10.100.10.30,10.200.0.158
dhcp-authoritative
```

The config of the secondary BIND server:

```
zone "example.com" {
  type slave;
  masters { 10.100.10.254; };
  file "/etc/bind/db.example.com";
};

zone "10.in-addr.arpa" {
  type slave;
  masters { 10.100.10.254; };
  file "/etc/bind/db.10";
};
```

Comment: Please add your current configurations. Also... I answered one of your previous questions on DNS.. Did that help or not?

Comment: @Tom: oh sorry. I completely reorganized my DNS environment and lost track of the accepted answers (which I follow religiously :)). Thanks. I will update my question with the full relevant configuration

Comment: I mostly wanted to know whether it works or not as I want to include your question in the chapter on DNS that I'm writing. It should make for a challenging exercise!

Comment: @Tom: oh nice, good luck with the book (I know from experience that this is tough). As I said I reorganized the whole DNS setup but if you are looking for some challenges / exercises I could give you my current setup (which involves containers and DNS servers, and a split view between records on Internet and internal.

Comment: I don't use **dnsmasq** but the documentation species that `auth-sec-servers` should contain a list of domains, so did you try specifying the FQDNs instead of only the hostnames?

Comment: @Tom: yes, and beside the transfer of example.com goes though (to the same secondaries). It is just the reverse which fails.

Comment: Can we also see the config for the reverse zone on BIND?

Comment: @Tom: I updated the question with the BIND config

Comment: First thing that comes to mind, does the file exist, is it writable by the `named` user and/or is the directory writable by that user to create the file?

Comment: @Tom: yes. In addition the `/etc/bind/db.example.com` which is next to it is created/updated without problems.

Comment: The secondary bind config is irrelevant because command line transfers will also fail. I have exactly the same problem. I can do forward zone transfers; For reverse zones, `host -t SOA ...` works fine and it reports itself; but `host -t AXFR ...` fails. Individual PTR lookups work fine.

Answer (score 1):

**CLEANUP EDIT with PROPOSED PATCH**

This is not possible yet so I have created a [fork](https://github.com/basezen/dnsmasq) to stand as a proposed patch to [Simon Kelley's official repository](http://thekelleys.org.uk/gitweb/?p=dnsmasq.git;a=summary) to address this. Please try it out!

Currently, while `dnsmasq` *creates* and *serves individually* the necessary `PTR` records, and delivers the correct `SOA` and `IN` records for `0.0.0.in-addr.arpa`, given the line:

`auth-zone=example.com,10.0.0.0/8,lan0,br0`

it simply will not transfer a full zone.

If you declare `auth-zone=0.0.10.in-addr.arpa` that will output a garbled zone.

Note in the man page:

```
Note that at present, reverse (in-addr.arpa and ip6.arpa) zones are
not available in zone transfers, so there is no point arranging
secondary servers for reverse lookups.
```

Comment: Thanks for a great answer.  What's the status of that branch?  For others in this boat I've put in the reverse zone as a `forward only` zone on the secondary back to dnsmasq so at least we get correct lookups with some caching all around the network.